# window.open browser issue in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am using:

```
window.open(url, 'XXXX', 'toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=no,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

to open a new window from inside a JavaScript function. `url` is dynamically generated. This works perfectly in IE but Firefox and Chrome open the parent window's URL in the new pop up window. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show us the code that generates `url`? Usually, when something doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome but it does work in IE, it's your code and IE that have a problem, not the other browsers :)

Comment: Have you tried it without the option string (i.e. `toolbar=....`)?

Answer (score 0):

As the other guy said, it's probably the code that generates the URL that's the problem.

Check the direction of the slashes which you use in your URL, it should be `/` as shown on the browser address bar.

I've recently made a mistake where I used `\` instead of `/`.

Using the `windows.open` function, the URL opened up correctly in chrome, but failed with firefox.

Changing the directions of the slashes fixed the problem for me.